# How to use OpenLayers 3 with a WMS supplied by MapServer?

Tags: openlayers, mapserver, jquery

I'm not able to centralize my map in OpenLayers / MapServer , it appears at the top . The " center " do not work . Below my code to better analyze . I did not post the mapfile why I did an experiment with the same file in OpenLayers 2 and it worked right.

```
//Javascript
var perimetro = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8081/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe',
      params: {
          LAYERS  : 'perimetro' ,
          mode    : 'map', 
          CRS     : 'EPSG:31982',
          map     : 'c:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/openlayers/maps/arapoti.map', 
          FORMAT  : 'image/png'
      },
      serverType  : 'mapserver',
      extent: [616080.773587 , 7327639.675000 , 622114.038913 , 7331307.325000]
  })
});

var bairros = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8081/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe',
      params: {
          LAYERS  : 'bairros' ,
          mode    : 'map', 
          CRS     : 'EPSG:31982',
          map     : 'c:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/openlayers/maps/arapoti.map', 
          FORMAT  : 'image/png'
      },
      serverType  : 'mapserver',
      extent: [616080.773587 , 7327639.675000 , 622114.038913 , 7331307.325000]
  })
});



var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [perimetro , bairros],
    projection : new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'EPSG:31982',
        units: 'm'
    }),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [622114.038913 , 7331307.325000],
        zoom: 5
     });
```

Comment: Please try defining the projection inside the `View` object. If it doesn't solve the problem, you can try to call `view.setCenter` after the map has been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

the previous code does not yet work with ol3.
 So use the following syntax: is tested with POSTGIS and Mapserver !

```
        var map = new ol.Map({ 
  target: 'map',
  renderer: 'canvas', 
   maxResolution: 156543.0399,
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([ new ol.control.ScaleLine({ units:'metric' }) ]),
  layers: layers,
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 9
  })
});

 var layers_parcelle =   new ol.layer.Image({
          source : new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url : 'http://192.168.1.11/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/Motors_importSIG/mapfile/toutes_les_parcelles.map',
            params: {
              // these are simply added to http-get parameter
              'LAYERS' : 'pp',
              'TRANSPARENT' : 'true'
            },
            })
        });
map.addLayer(layers_parcelle);
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this solves the question?

Comment: this solution show the center of the map only after projection scr default. I misunderstood the question. so sorry

Comment: I am not saying your answer is wrong. Giving your answer more information is a good thing, so I am just suggesting you explain better how this is done and why. To me it seems like you reproject the coordinate and that this solves the issue. Although the EPSG you are using does not relate to those in the question. I suggest you include that information in your answer :-) And if you consider your answer erroneous you simply delete it.

Comment: :-)
EPSG: 3857 (default projection OL3)
the syntax view: [622114.038913, 7331307.325000] Displays point (622114.038913, 7331307.325000) but not in EPSG: 3857.
So I have reprojecter on EPSG: 3857 for the right location on map.thank you,